# Create a response for invalid and incomplete end points using the Serverless Framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a series of HTTP endpoints that involve lambda functions that hit detail information like so:

```
products/1
users/1
package/998134
```

There is not a corresponding endpoint for `products/`, `users/` or `package/`. I have a custom authorizer around the `users/{id}` and `package/{id}` endpoints.

If a user goes to `users/` or `packages/` using `GET` they receive `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}`. If they hit these end points with `POST` (a valid option for my endpoint if they were to also pass the ID) they receive

```
{'message': "Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=MYTOKENHERE"}
```

Is there a way to adjust either of these messages? My first thought was to just create that associated end points:

```
GET users/
POST users/
GET products/
POST products/
GET package/
POST package
```

But that quickly gets to be a lot of work because I have more than three of these end points to do. I also need to include `DELETE` and `PUT` on a few of those.

Can I easily create a response for invalid or incomplete endpoints?

My serverless.yml has definitions look like this currently:

```
show_user:
  handler: users/show_users.return_user
  events:
    - http:
        path: users/{id}
        method: get
        cors: true
update_user:
  handler: users/update_user.update_user
  events:
    - http:
        path: users/{id}
        method: post
        cors: true
        authorizer: ${self:custom.authorizer.users}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do something similar recently. I did it with a configuration like this:

```
error_messages:
  handler: custom_errors/errors.invalid_path
  events:
    - http
        path: users/
        method: any
    - http
        path: product/
        method: any
    - http
        path: package/
        method: any
```

Then create the handler at the specified location and return the result you wish. In this case, the handler would be at `custom_errors/errors.invalid_path`

In my case, I returned an HTTP 404 with a custom message saying that an `{id}` was required.

The `method: any` line will catch all HTTP verbs, so you will only need to add three lines for each endpoint that you want this protection on, instead of a group for each individual HTTP verb.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this using the {proxy+} catchall feature of ApiGateway like so:

```
no-endpoint:
    description: catch all non-existent enpoints with 404 - must be 
last http
    handler: src/functions/api-controller.noEndpoint
    events:
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: any
          cors: true
```

**Note**: this *MUST* be the last http endpoint in your serverless file so that other valid endpoints are not caught. You can read more about it here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/api-gateway-update-new-features-simplify-api-development/